# SQL to set a date and constant number

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I am creating a database to track projects.  In it I have several milestones.  On the form each milestone has a label and a textbox next to it. The project manager will go in and type the date of that milestone.

What I need to do is based on the textbox that date is typed in it will save date and milestoneID to a table.

If you look at the Form and Table images attached:
You see on the form they enter the date next to milestone.

On the table you see the each date gets a schedule ID (autonumber), the projectID gets assigned to it (another table), and then the milestoneID(phaseID) followed by the StartDate.  Ignore the end date.  I need that schedPlanPhaseID to fill in based on which text box then entered a date in on the form.

I am still very new to SQL and access so sorry if I miss something obvious.

[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0eJl.png)
[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOxGm.png)

Comment: Try to add a data picker because in textbox date can get different input format everytime that's why there can be problem with storing data. Or try to give a fixed date format to user so that they can fill date as you tell. After that you can simply store the data as date in db

Comment: I may have not been very clear about my question.  They have 5 boxes to enter dates.  Each box is aligned with a milestone.  When they enter the date into that box I need it to not only copy over the date, but a numeric ID associated with the milestone. So in the table it would fill one column with the numeric ID associated with that milestone and in another it would fill with the date they entered.

Comment: What will be the length of your numeric ID. Is there any limitation ?